# Mouse Click java

Tags: java, swing, paint, keylistener, mouselistener

I followed a tutorial on creating a Maze Game in java. After completing it, I decided to add a few things (Main menu, more levels, etc). I am currently stuck at the Main Menu because I cannot get mouse input to work. I am trying to switch to screen = 1 when I left click in the start game box. This is my current code for the class.

```
package Maze;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    private Timer timer;    
    private Map m;
    private Player p;
    private int screen = 0;
    private String Message = "";
    private Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 48);
    private Font start = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 36);
    private Rectangle start2 = new Rectangle(135,350,180,55);


    public Board(){
        m = new Map();
        p = new Player();
        addKeyListener(new Al());
        addMouseListener(new A2());
        setFocusable(true);     
        timer = new Timer(25,this);
        timer.start();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
        if(m.getMap(p.getTileX(),p.getTileY()).equals("f")){
            Message = "Winner";
            screen = 10;
        }
        repaint();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        if(screen==0){
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 464, 485);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.setFont(font);
            g.drawString("Maze Game", 100,50);
            g.setFont(start);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString("Created by: ", 135,90);
            g.drawString("Chad Jordan", 125,130);
            g.setColor(Color.PINK);
            g.fillRect(start2.x, start2.y, start2.width, start2.height);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString("Start Game", start2.x, start2.y+40);

        }

        if((screen==1)){
            for(int y = 0; y<14;y++){
                for(int x=0; x<14; x++){
                    if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("g")){
                        g.drawImage(m.getGrass(),  x*32, y*32, null);
                    }
                    if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("w")){
                        g.drawImage(m.getWall(),  x*32, y*32, null);
                    }
                    if(m.getMap(x,y).equals("f")){
                        g.drawImage(m.getFinish(), x*32, y*32, null);
                    }
                }
            }
            g.drawImage(p.getPlayer(), p.getTileX()*32, p.getTileY()*32, null);
        }
        if(screen==10){
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.setFont(font);
            g.drawString(Message, 150,200);
        }

    }

    public class A2 extends MouseAdapter{
        public void MousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            int mx = e.getX();
            int my = e.getY();
            System.out.println("2");
            if((screen ==0) && start2.contains(mx,my)){
                screen=1;
                System.out.println("1");
            }
        }
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }
    }

    public class Al extends KeyAdapter{
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            int keycode = e.getKeyCode();
            if(( keycode == KeyEvent.VK_W) || (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_UP)){
                if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX(),p.getTileY() -1).equals("w")){
                    p.move(0, -1);
                }
            }
            if(( keycode == KeyEvent.VK_A) || (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)){
                if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX()-1,p.getTileY()).equals("w")){
                p.move(-1, 0);
                }
            }
            if(( keycode == KeyEvent.VK_D) || (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)){
                if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX()+1,p.getTileY()).equals("w")){
                    p.move(1, 0);
                }
            }
            if(( keycode == KeyEvent.VK_S) || (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)){
                if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX(),p.getTileY() +1).equals("w")){
                    p.move(0, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

        }
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

        }   
    }
}
```

I used "System.out.println("1");" to see if it registers a mouse press but it does not print.

Comment: When you put `System.out.println("1");` outside of your if statement, it still doesn't print? also, why print? just put a break point and debug? (you can do so even without using an IDE, though one will help...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is capitalization from what I see

you have implemented MousePressed with a capital M

```
       public void MousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            int mx = e.getX();
            int my = e.getY();
            System.out.println("2");
            if((screen ==0) && start2.contains(mx,my)){
                screen=1;
                System.out.println("1");
            }
        }
```

and also with a lowercase m:

```
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }
```

simply change the capital M to lowercase m and remove the redundant mousePressed call

e.g.

```
 public class A2 extends MouseAdapter{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        int mx = e.getX();
        int my = e.getY();
        System.out.println("2");
        if((screen ==0) && start2.contains(mx,my)){
            screen=1;
            System.out.println("1");
        }
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue. I had been working on it for a few hours ><

Answer (score 4):

The main problem your having is you've named your mouse pressed method incorrectly

Change

```
public void MousePressed(MouseEvent e)
```

To

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
```

I would recommend than you make use of the `@Override` annotation, which will cause a compiler error if you make this mistake

I would also encourage the use of the key bindings API over KeyListener and paintComponent over paint.

You may also find a call to repaint after you change the screen  variable will update the screen

Comment: Yep. and +1 for mentioning `@Override`

Answer (score -1):

public void nousePressed(MouseEvent e) **not** public void MousePressed(MouseEvent e)

Comment: The question is already answered, and your answer has a typo.